# How to show JavaScript alert in Blazor code

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I want to show alert after a button click in Blazor. Below is the html and server side code

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="InsertForecast"> Submit</button>
        </div>

 public async Task InsertForecast()
        {
//want to add the alert here


 bool confirmed = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure?");
}
```

I tried adding using `Microsoft.JSInterop` in the code behind file but the `JsRuntime` object giving the following error

> Object does not contain a definition for InvokeAsync and the best extension method overload JSObjectreferenceExtension.InvokeAsync expects parameter of type 'IJsObjectreference'

Comment: I tried that approach but I am getting an error

Object doesnot contain a definition for invokeasync

Comment: What is the error? And can you add in the question whatever you have tried so far

Comment: @Vivek, Added the error message .Please check

Comment: you need to define the confirm function in a separate js file and include it

Comment: be sure you has `@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime`. I just check and work. @vivek , it's not necesary create a separate js file

Comment: @Eliseo yes you are right, we don’t need separate file. But it’s for separation of code and better maintainability. JS code at separate place

Comment: @Eliseo, the code is still not working for me .Can you please give some sample code or a fiddle for that

Comment: it's the first time I use this online-editor: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/2hsr04eo  but really it's only your code and comment

Comment: Thanks a ton Eliseo, This works if the code is in same file but will it work if there is a separate code file for the html and I have to showthe alert on button click event code behind ?

Comment: I would recommend learning the Blazor way. You could easily create a reusable dialog component, or download a free open source widget like blazored: https://github.com/Blazored/Modal

Comment: To inject IJSRuntime in a Blazor component I think that should be `[Inject]private IJSRuntime JsRuntime {get;set;}` :https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/injecting-dependencies-into-blazor-components/

Comment: Thanks it is  nowworking as expected :)